# Unity NullReferenceException with Lists

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So making an asteroid game, trying to spawn in 4 asteroids, one in each centre section of each side. Code is below for the spawnerScript & the Initialize method.

Got a couple of errors/Warnings:

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
> object (UnityEditor.PropertyHandler.isArrayReordable

> Should not be capturing when there is a hotcontrol

If someone could point out WHY it's giving that error would be appreciated

```
[SerializeField] GameObject prefabAsteroid;
List<GameObject> asteroids = new List<GameObject>();
List<Vector3> screenSides = new List<Vector3>();
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    //get screen numbers
    float screenHeight = ScreenUtils.ScreenTop - ScreenUtils.ScreenBottom;
    float screenWidth = ScreenUtils.ScreenRight - ScreenUtils.ScreenLeft;

    //collect all screen sides
    screenSides.Add(new Vector2(ScreenUtils.ScreenLeft,screenHeight/2));
    screenSides.Add(new Vector2(ScreenUtils.ScreenTop, screenWidth / 2));
    screenSides.Add(new Vector2(ScreenUtils.ScreenRight, screenHeight / 2));
    screenSides.Add(new Vector2(ScreenUtils.ScreenBottom, screenWidth / 2));
    //loop through each direction(Up,Left,Down,Right) and
    //Instantiate asteroid on center of each side.
    int i = 0;
    foreach (Direction dir in System.Enum.GetValues(typeof(Direction)))
    {

        GameObject pa = Instantiate<GameObject>(prefabAsteroid);
        //add to list
        asteroids.Add(pa);
        pa.GetComponent<Asteroid>().Initialize(dir, screenSides[i]);
        i++;
    }
```

---

```
public void Initialize(Direction direction, Vector2 location)
{
    transform.position = location;
    float angle = Random.Range(0 * Mathf.Deg2Rad, 30 * Mathf.Deg2Rad);
    Vector2 forceMagnitude = new Vector2(Random.Range(minImpulse, maxImpulse), Random.Range(minImpulse, maxImpulse));
    if(direction == Direction.Right)
    {
        angle +=-15*Mathf.Deg2Rad;
    }
    else if (direction == Direction.Left)
    {
        angle +=165 * Mathf.Deg2Rad;
    }
    else if (direction == Direction.Up)
    {
        angle += 75 * Mathf.Deg2Rad;
    }
    else if (direction == Direction.Down)
    {
        angle += 255 * Mathf.Deg2Rad;
    }
    Vector2 moveDirection = new Vector2(Mathf.Cos(angle), Mathf.Sin(angle));
    rb.AddForce(forceMagnitude * moveDirection, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
}
```

Tried storing instantiated object into list, tried grabbing  component from that but still same error

Comment: Where is it throwing the error? At what point?

Comment: My guess would be that either `Instantiate<GameObject>(prefabAsteroid);` is returning a Null, or `pa.GetComponent<Asteroid>()` is returning a null.

Comment: I do note that `prefabAsteroid` is declared but never gets a value. So it starts off a null (unless GameObject is a struct).  Possibly that's the reason it's throwing.

Comment: A stack trace would also be helpful.

Comment: Also, in your `Initialize` routine, is `rb` ever declared, let alone assigned to?

Comment: How does one do a stack trace (for future needs)

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it.

Error was the rigidbody component 'rb' wasn't within the Initialise (was in Start() method but that hasn't run at this point) so was considered null. Just noticed Ann.L saying same thing